# How can I sample instructions executed or retired with Linux perf?

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, x86, perf

How can I get a reasonable sample of instructions executed or retired<sup>1</sup> using `perf`?

Stuff like `perf record -e instructions` gives obviously wrong results. Obviously wrong here means they appear to sample slow instructions based on their execution time.

E.g., for the following loop:

```
.loop:
    mov rdx, rsi
    xor rax, rax
    div rdi
    dec rcx
    jne .loop
```

You will get 99.5% to 100% of the samples on the `div` or `dec` instructions (depending on if you have 1-instruction skid, or not), yet obviously all these instructions must be retired at the same rate (it is a basic block).

Typical results for a "skid 1" event like `inst_retired.any_p` (3704 samples):

[image: typical]

[Source, build and execution instructions](https://gist.github.com/travisdowns/a44f8dd2cd87bbe8fd4cdde89e7f1d08) for this benchmark.

---

<sup>1</sup> I mention both because the distinction is important in principle (the former would count speculatively executed, but never retired instructions), although I'm happy for an answer for either.

Comment: Does `inst_retired.any` or `inst_retired.any_p` not do the trick for you?  (The latter is a precise event using programmable counters, not the hard-wired counter.)  For "executed", a quick look on SKL only turns up uop events, not instruction events. 
 (BTW, which "obviously wrong" results are you referring to?  Could be useful for future readers to have a brief example of that, or at least a description of the wrongness.)

Comment: @PeterCordes No they give junk answers for instructions, they are very similar to `cycles:*`: all the samples accumulate on the slow instructions, even within a basic block. I added an example. Both your suggestions show 99-100% of the samples on `dec` in my example, whereas the right answer should be 20% or 25% for each instruction since this is a basic block (the difference being down to how macro-fusion is handled).

Comment: It's nothing specific to `div` BTW. Any random example will be obviously wrong. I've never seen one that is right with these events: i.e., none respect basic blocks.

Comment: That may be unfixable, and is probably correlated to retirement groups of instructions that all retire in a single cycle.  I wonder if it's possible to program the sampling counter with a non-multiple-of-4 value to distribute randomly over instructions within groups?

Comment: @PeterCordes - I don't think groups are the main problem here. The main problem is that it stops mostly on slow instructions.

Comment: If instead of `div` you had `nop`, you'd still see clustered counts, right?  Even in a 4-uop loop.  Maybe tomorrow I'll try that with an odd or prime sample interval.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, you see clustered counts, like maybe every 4 instructions get a lot more samples. That's understandable as you point out. However, you also get larger scale clustering around slow instructions.

Comment: @osgx - Intel Ice Lake.